# Failed to parse source map in my terminal in vs code

Tags: javascript, antd

It said failed to parse source map after using import `antd/dist/antd.css`

I tried looking for the source map so that I can rectify the issues since chat.openai.com provided me ways how to rectify it though using .env file but I tried that it still didn't work. Please this the error I am facing below

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community ooh okay like what I am saying is that the source map can't be read it is saying invalid links

Comment: @dglory1 community is a bot. Please update the question

Comment: I don't get what u mean by I should update the question?

Comment: _ Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need_ - please edit the question to include a [mcve] showing the issue.